# How to convert a text file content to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a dictionary value to a text file. Now I want to read the same text file to extract the content as a dictionary with Keys and values.

The text file content is in this format

```
   '5945-01-311-3597': {'NSN': '5945-01-311-3597', 'Nomenclature': 'ARMATURE, ELECTROMAG', 'RFQ_Date': '2-13-2019', 'RFQ_QTY': ' 25', 'Time': '2019-08-14 20:17:56', 'Add_method': 'Dibbs Extract'}, '3110-00-365-4766': {'NSN': '3110-00-365-4766', 'Nomenclature': 'BEARING, BALL, ANNULA', 'RFQ_Date': '2-13-2019', 'RFQ_QTY': ' 29', 'Time': '2019-08-14 20:17:56', 'Add_method': 'Dibbs Extract'}, '3120-01-584-4379': {'NSN': '3120-01-584-4379', 'Nomenclature': 'BEARING, WASHER, THRU', 'RFQ_Date': '2-13-2019', 'RFQ_QTY': ' 1', 'Time': '2019-08-14 20:17:56', 'Add_method': 'Dibbs Extract'},
```

so one key value pair will look like this

```
  '5945-01-311-3597': {'NSN': '5945-01-311-3597', 'Nomenclature': 'ARMATURE, ELECTROMAG', 'RFQ_Date': '2-13-2019', 'RFQ_QTY': ' 25', 'Time': '2019-08-14 20:17:56', 'Add_method': 'Dibbs Extract'}
```

with 5945-01-311-3597 being the key here and everything else in brack being the values.

```
 RFQ_file=open("RFQs/8-14-2019-rfq.txt", "r")

 RFQ_file_content =RFQ_file.read()

 rfqDict = RFQ_file_content.split('},')
```

the above code produces this output

'5945-01-311-3597': {'NSN': '5945-01-311-3597', 'Nomenclature': 'ARMATURE, ELECTROMAG', 'RFQ_Date': '2-13-2019', 'RFQ_QTY': ' 25', 'Time': '2019-08-14 20:17:56', 'Add_method': 'Dibbs Extract'

what is the best way to convert the text file content above to a dictionary so that I can get the values for a specific key ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` package to convert `string` to `dict`.

For example,

```py
import json

with open(PATH_TO_YOUR_DATA, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then you can get the value you want from dict `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Note you may have trailing comma in the file which may fail the JSON loading.

Try:

```
import json

# read data
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

data = data.strip().rstrip(',')  # remove potential blank lines and trailing comma

your_dict = json.loads(data)
```

When you are saving the file, try using `json.dumps(your_dict)` to avoid these issues.

Comment: You may want to 1) manually add a `{` at the beginning of `data`, and/or add `}` at the end - depends on how you saved the file originally. 2) Replace all the single quotes to double quotes as per JSON requirement.